# Keep size when AutoSize is turned off

Tags: .net, winforms, autosize, sizing

I have a form which initialy sizes itself to its contents (a `UserControl` placed on location 0, 0) by setting `AutoSize` to true and `AutoSizeMode` to `GrowAndShrink`.

After initialization, I want the form to take control and turn off AutoSizing and make the UserControl `Dock.Fill`.

The problem is that when turning off `AutoSize`, the form regains its previous size instead of keeping its current size.
I can store the Size before turning off AutoSize, and restore it afterwards, but you still get sizing events (you could see the form flicker).

Is there any way to have a form keep its current size and not have any sizing events fired when turning off `AutoSize`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the MinimumSize property of the form before turning off the AutoSize property:

```
this.MinimumSize = this.Size;
this.AutoSize = false;
```

Comment: This is working solution. I would add resetting of MinimumSize to Size.Empty, if user should be able to resize form to less then initial size.

Comment: I my case I rather need to set `this.MaximumSize = this.Size;` since the form is initially large than its contents. Resetting them afterward indeed seems the most elegant solution. Thanks to both!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - I wanted the form to grow or shrink using AutoSize when a button was pressed, and then return to allowing the user to resize it manually.

Currently my solution is in the button event:

```
    Me.AutoSize = True
    uiStopAutoSizeTimer.Start()
```

And then have a separate method to both turn off the AutoSize, and keep the size that AutoSize had used on the form.

```
Private Sub uiStopAutoSizeTimer_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles uiStopAutoSizeTimer.Tick
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    Dim tempSize = Me.Size
    Me.AutoSize = False
    Me.Size = tempSize
    uiStopAutoSizeTimer.Enabled = False
    Me.ResumeLayout()
End Sub
```

It works, but it just feels clunky.